# PHP DOMDocument insertBefore throws "Not Found Error"

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have a DOMDocument and I am trying to insert an node before an other.

```
$doc = $parent->ownerDocument;
$xref_node = $doc->importNode($xref, true);
$ref = $doc->importNode($ref, true);
$parent->insertBefore($xref_node, $ref_node);
```

$parent, $xref and $ref are DOMElements.

Somehow, this is generating an "Not Found Error" on the line where I am using insertBefore.

Any idea why? I am using here the ownerDocument of the $parent, importing the two nodes $xref and $ref in this document and then try to use the insert before, on nodes from the same document.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug: `$ref =` should be `$ref_node =`